# C# graphing with ZedGraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Is it possible to select a point and simply delete it off the graph so that the image can be saved without that point?

Comment: @everyone please to be answering immediately

Comment: Yes Drill sgt. Would you like fries with that?

Comment: @mikos please get me a sandwhich ASAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can do it in this way:
 Subscribe for the `MouseClick` event, find the nearest point and delete it.

Here you can find an example how to subscribe for event in `ZedGraph`: http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Edit_Points_by_Dragging_the_Mouse [website down, link broken]

You will need to use [`FindNearestPoint`](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_GraphPane_FindNearestPoint_1.htm) method to find clicked point. this method will return you the `CurveItem` and `ID` of the clicked point. You can delete it just by using the [`RemovePoint`](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_CurveItem_RemovePoint.htm) method of the `CurveItem` object.

Just remember, that after every change you need to call `Invalidate` or `Refresh` method of your [control](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_ZedGraphControl.htm) to refresh the chart.

Comment: The link to zedgraph.org is (effectively) broken now.

Comment: @Gacek Not sure if you're still in the zedgraph game.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953879/working-with-zedgraph-xdate-values-to-set-majorminorstep-and-basetic-values-for

Comment: Not really, sorry! :(